# Group similar items in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to make a POS system right now.
I want to make my JTable add existing items to the same row while adjusting their quantity price.

For example: Product 1 already exists in the table and I want to add the same Product 1 but with different quantity. That additional product 1 will add its quantity to the previous Product 1 already in the table and then adjust the price of the product 1.

Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: i only manage to add up products in the jtable but same products dont add to each other so pretty much it gets crowded by the same products ie. i add p1 for this quantity then i add another p1 with different quantity, but the same product dont add its quantity to save space in the jtable.

Comment: How does the insertion of new data work in your table?

Comment: well it does just add the product name then if i add the same product it will just appear again in the table

Comment: I mean how is the user interface. Do you have a dialog? Or does it input by typing directly into the table?

Comment: i have a combobox and a button and a table and a textbox. first ill input a integer in the textbox then choose a product in the combobox and hit the button and then it will appear in the table thats how my code works..

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question and what's there in the comment. I think you basically need to manipulate the data in the JTable using the table model. ([Oracle's tutorial on Jtable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html))
Logic would be

1. When use click button to add product and quantity, you should find out whether the product has been in the table or not

   model.getValueAt(i, PRODUCT_COL) != null && model.getValueAt(i, PRODUCT_COL).equals(product)
2. If the product has been added, find out the original quantity and add the new quantity to the original quanity

   int orignialQuantity = Integer.parseInt(model.getValueAt(existingProductRowIndex, QUANTITY_COL).toString());
                   model.setValueAt(orignialQuantity + quantity, existingProductRowIndex, QUANTITY_COL);
3. Otherwise, insert a new row for the new product

   model.addRow(new Object[]{product, quantity});

Running example:

```
public class POS extends JFrame {
String[] columns = {"Product", "Quantity"};
private final static int PRODUCT_COL = 0;
private final static int QUANTITY_COL = 1;
TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(new String[]{"Apple", "Banana"});
JTextField quantityJtf = new JTextField(10);
JButton jButton = new JButton("Add");

POS() {
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    this.add(comboBox);
    this.add(quantityJtf);
    this.add(jButton);

    jButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
}

private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String product = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityJtf.getText().trim());

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        int rowCount = model.getRowCount();
        int existingProductRowIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i) {
            if (model.getValueAt(i, PRODUCT_COL) != null && model.getValueAt(i, PRODUCT_COL).equals(product)) {
                existingProductRowIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (existingProductRowIndex > -1) {
            int orignialQuantity = Integer.parseInt(model.getValueAt(existingProductRowIndex, QUANTITY_COL).toString());
            model.setValueAt(orignialQuantity + quantity, existingProductRowIndex, QUANTITY_COL);
        } else {
            model.addRow(new Object[]{product, quantity});
        }
    }
```